# Pandas groupby equal consecutive column values based on index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Having a dataset like this:

| Index | Role | Name | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Provider | Alex | 7 |
| 2 | Provider | William | 7.5 |
| 7 | Provider | Juan | 5.5 |
| 15 | Provider | Pedro | 4.5 |
| 25 | Client | George | 8 |
| 26 | Provider | Mark | 9.4 |
| 37 | Client | James | 8.1 |
| 39 | Transporter | Anthony | 9.5 |
| 50 | Transporter | Jason | 7 |

I'm trying to group the consecutive rows with same **Role** value. I can achieve this by using the following sentence:

```
df = df.groupby((df.Role!= df.Role.shift()).cumsum()).agg(
            Role = ('Role', 'first'),
            Name = ('Name', ' '.join), 
            Grade = ('Grade', 'mean')
        ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This would leave the dataframe looking like this:

| Index | Role | Name | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Provider | Alex William Juan Pedro | 6.125 |
| 2 | Client | George | 8 |
| 3 | Provider | Mark | 9.4 |
| 4 | Client | James | 8.1 |
| 5 | Transporter | Anthony Jason | 8.25 |

Now I would like to add a new rule. I would like to only group when the dataframe index has a difference of 5 units at maximum from previous row:

| Index | Role | Name | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Provider | Alex William Juan | 6.67 |
| 2 | Provider | Pedro | 4.5 |
| 3 | Client | George | 8 |
| 4 | Provider | Mark | 9.4 |
| 5 | Client | James | 8.1 |
| 6 | Transporter | Anthony | 9.5 |
| 7 | Transporter | Jason | 7 |

How could I achieve this? Also if there is any grouping method more efficient, it is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build two masks, one to identify the Role change, and one to identify the difference of index above threshold (with [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html)). Then combine the masks with `|` before running the `cumsum`:

```
m1 = df.Role!= df.Role.shift()
m2 = df['Index'].diff().gt(5)

out = df.groupby((m1|m2).cumsum()).agg(
            Role = ('Role', 'first'),
            Name = ('Name', ' '.join), 
            Grade = ('Grade', 'mean')
        ).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
          Role               Name     Grade
0     Provider  Alex William Juan  6.666667
1     Provider              Pedro  4.500000
2       Client             George  8.000000
3     Provider               Mark  9.400000
4       Client              James  8.100000
5  Transporter            Anthony  9.500000
6  Transporter              Jason  7.000000
```

Intermediates:

```
   Index         Role     Name  Grade     m1     m2  m1|m2  cumsum
0      1     Provider     Alex    7.0   True  False   True       1
1      2     Provider  William    7.5  False  False  False       1
2      7     Provider     Juan    5.5  False  False  False       1
3     15     Provider    Pedro    4.5  False   True   True       2
4     25       Client   George    8.0   True   True   True       3
5     26     Provider     Mark    9.4   True  False   True       4
6     37       Client    James    8.1   True   True   True       5
7     39  Transporter  Anthony    9.5   True  False   True       6
8     50  Transporter    Jason    7.0  False   True   True       7
```